# Steps required to use Docker

Tags: docker

Understanding

1. When a docker container is started, it should have a foreground
   process, else the container will stop immediately.
2. If the foreground process is started in Dockerfile, then the build
   step will not get completed.
3. run = create + start
4. exec can be used only when the container is running
5. One of the arguments of run is a command which to be executed inside
   the container. start doesn't support such a command.

Based on the above, I have come out with the following:

1. Build Image: Dockerfile will contain only the environment creation
   steps (Installation of software, creation of folders kind of steps)
2. First time use of the container: run is to be used along with the command (or a script inside the image) to start the foreground process
3. Subsequent use: The container is to be started using start

Is this an acceptable way? If not, what corrections do I need to make? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are in the right track as image creation and containers are different topics.
You may want to look at some of the free, self paced training lessons online to get a better foundation of the concepts:

A couple good ones IMO:

- http://training.play-with-docker.com/
- https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-docker